# How to get all choices from a drop down list

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dropdown

The extension I'm trying to write is meant to create a playlist of videos in a random order.  I'm able to create the playlist for videos on the current page, however, the videos are separated by season so I'm unable to get all of them.  So far I haven't been able to get a list of the other videos because they only show up if you select the season with the drop down.  The issue I'm having is cycling through the drop down.  The "Select-menu-outer" class doesn't appear with the list until the drop down has been expanded and I can't get it to expand programatically.

Here is the code before I expand the dropdown:

```
<div role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--value" class="Select-input" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" style="border: 0px; width: 1px; display: inline-block;"></div>
```

and here is the code after I expand the dropdown:

```
<div role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-owns="react-select-2--list" aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--option-14" class="Select-input" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" style="border: 0px; width: 1px; display: inline-block;"></div>
```

I have tried many different solutions such as

```
var sel = document.getElementById("yourSelectId");
var opts = sel.options;
var array = new Array();
for(i = 0; i < opts.length; i++)
{
    array.push(opts[i].value);
}
```

but haven't been able to get anything to work.

How would I go about getting all the information from each individual drop down option? The main problem i'm facing is that the element disappears when the drop down list isn't selected.  Any help would be majorly appreciated.  I've read the google docs and searched for over a week but haven't had any luck.  Even if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great

Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to Javascript.  I usually use Java and Python, but I wanted to try this as a side project.

Comment: That's not a `<select>` element so it doesn't have `options` property. You can set a subtree modification breakpoint in devtools - either on this DIV or on the entire BODY since the contents may be elsewhere. Once you know what to look for, you can do it via MutationObserver in your content script.